# Problem in labeled vertices with tkz-graph and beamer

Tags: beamer, tkz-graph

Please the below code work perfectly in article latex class, but when i try to put it in IAStheme of beamer the labels are strange.

**The code**

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
% or whatever
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% or whatever

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,topaths,fit,arrows.meta,backgrounds,calc,trees,hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
%\title[Identification In Digraph] % (optional, use only with long paper titles)

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{122,163,204}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Locally transitive}
         
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
      \SetGraphUnit{2}
      \renewcommand*{\VertexLineColor}{black}
      \renewcommand*{\VertexLightFillColor}{white}
      \renewcommand*{\VertexSmallMinSize}{6pt}
      \renewcommand*{\VertexLineWidth}{1pt}
      %\SetVertexNoLabel
      \GraphInit[vstyle=Welsh]
      \Vertices{circle}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7} % the ... syntax doesn't work here
      \AddVertexColor{myblue}{1,5}
     
      \SetUpEdge[style={->,thick},color=black]
      \foreach \i in {1,...,7}
      { 
        \foreach
        [evaluate=\j as \k using {ifthenelse(Mod(\i+\j,7)==0,int(\i+\j),int(Mod(\i+\j,7)))}]
        \j in {1,2,3}
        { 
        \Edge(\i)(\k)
          }
        }
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

it gives me
[image]

I don't know how to set the correcte label (ie 1 2 ... 7)

Comment: your MWE can not be compiled since it use specific styles. Please remove from your document all what is not necessary to show your problem and leave just one frame with your image and public available `beamer` styles.

Comment: @HTeX Can you show an example of how this works in article class? If I remove everything beamer specific and try with article, I get exactly the same result.

Comment: @samcarter the example with article class is given below:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to compile without `babel`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

%\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
% or whatever
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% or whatever

%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,topaths,fit,arrows.meta,backgrounds,calc,trees,hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
%\title[Identification In Digraph] % (optional, use only with long paper titles)

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{122,163,204}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Locally transitive}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
      \SetGraphUnit{2}
      \renewcommand*{\VertexLineColor}{black}
      \renewcommand*{\VertexLightFillColor}{white}
      \renewcommand*{\VertexSmallMinSize}{6pt}
      \renewcommand*{\VertexLineWidth}{1pt}
      %\SetVertexNoLabel
      \GraphInit[vstyle=Welsh]
      \Vertices{circle}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7} % the ... syntax doesn't work here
      \AddVertexColor{myblue}{1,5}

      \SetUpEdge[style={->,thick},color=black]
      \foreach \i in {1,...,7}
      { 
        \foreach
        [evaluate=\j as \k using {ifthenelse(Mod(\i+\j,7)==0,int(\i+\j),int(Mod(\i+\j,7)))}]
        \j in {1,2,3}
        { 
        \Edge(\i)(\k)
          }
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 @samcarter, it's exactly what i want. have a good night.

Comment: you find the cause +1!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
*samcarter* found the cause of your problem: package `babel`. To be more specific, the cause is `french` option at its use. It overwrite some `tikz` code. For cure of this problem is  overcome this problem (for most non-English babel options) is defined `tikzlibrary`babel`. Just add it to used libraries and problem will be solved:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}% <-- this MWE also work with babel

\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, babel}% <-- added babel library

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\small
    \begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.45\linewidth}
    \[
\forall~v\in V(T),~deg^-(v)=deg^+(v)
\]
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.55\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \SetGraphUnit{2}
    \renewcommand*{\VertexLineColor}{white}
    \renewcommand*{\VertexLightFillColor}{red}
    \renewcommand*{\VertexLineWidth}{1pt}
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Welsh]
    \Vertices{circle}{1,2,3,4,5,6}
    \AddVertexColor{blue}{5,1}
    \SetUpEdge[style={-{Straight Barb[length=1mm,width=1.2mm]}, thick},color=red]
     \foreach \v [count=\vi from 2] in {1,...,5}{
     \foreach \vv in {\vi,...,6}{\Edge(\v)(\vv)};
     };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: don't load package which are already loaded by `beamer` (look in `beamer` documentation for details). Make preamble minimalistic as possible. Use LaTeX syntax for equations.

I cant test above MWE with your preamble since specific `beamer` theme is not (public) available.

Comment: Hi @Zarko, yes in simple beamer class work perfectly, unfortunatly the wrong label appear in IAS theme. I look for how i can add manualy a label to each vertex and keeping the commande \SetVertexNoLabel to hide the wrong one. This theme is available at http://fransoliehoek.net/index.php?fuseaction=var.beamer

Comment: @HTeX, than please make this theme somewhere available.